# Argument is not Numerical or Logical: returning NA

Tags: r

I have a data set with weight values in a CSV file. My goal is to find the standard deviation of these values.

I have tried assigning a variable to the file, attaching it, then using the standard deviation function `sd()`, to find the standard deviation. In return, I get this error message:

> Argument is not Numerical or Logical: returning NA

My file looks like this:

```
weight.g
54.4
24.2
84.9
56.5
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
brains <- read.csv(file.choose())
attach(brains)
sd(brains)
```

Comment: And what is the error message you got?

Comment: the error message that is in the title: Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

Comment: You are trying to put a data.frame in the `sd` function. Don't you mean `sd(brains$weight.g)`? or whatever the column name is in the brains data.frame?